# find the Argument and Parameter in this code

Tags: python, parameters, arguments

Could you pls tell me that `keepdims=True` is parameter here or whatever?

```
lookback = 50
lb_data = X_train[:,-lookback:]
med = np.median(lb_data,axis=1,keepdims=True)
err = mape(y_train,med)
```

Comment: Parameters are the variables after the function name in the function definition. Arguments are the values passed when you call.

Comment: tnx.just for clarification: keepdims=True  is an Argument?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better answered by reviewing whatever material OP is learning the language from, or asking an instructor etc. The question is fundamentally about the terminology, not about actually doing the programming work.

Comment: `True` is the argument, `keepdims` is the parameter name that the argument corresponds to.

Comment: dear Karl Knechtel so you mean it is bad that some vague concept became clear for a beginner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keepdims is an optional parameter. If you pass False into the call, then False would be an argument passed to the keepdims parameter.

You can also explicitly pass True as an argument, but that is redundant, as the parameter is set to true by default if you don't pass any argument.

https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.median.html